# listview.builder wrapped inside expanded widget (and shrinkWrap: true) in a column is not building the ui

Tags: flutter, dart

I am not able to fix this error:

```
======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.
When a column is in a parent that does not provide a finite height constraint, for example if it is in a vertical scrollable, it will try to shrink-wrap its children along the vertical axis. Setting a flex on a child (e.g. using Expanded) indicates that the child is to expand to fill the remaining space in the vertical direction.
These two directives are mutually exclusive. If a parent is to shrink-wrap its child, the child cannot simultaneously expand to fit its parent.
```

I have tried to set set `shrinkWrap` to `true` for `ListView.builder` but got no success.

below is code for my donation screen:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:fan_say/components/app_background_screen.dart';
    import 'package:fan_say/components/custom_textfield.dart';
    import 'package:fan_say/components/custom_button.dart';
    
    class DonateScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      State<DonateScreen> createState() => _DonateScreenState();
    }
    
    class _DonateScreenState extends State<DonateScreen> {
      final TextEditingController searchController = TextEditingController();
    
      final TextEditingController cardController = TextEditingController();
    
      final TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();
    
      final TextEditingController dateController = TextEditingController();
    
      final TextEditingController cvvController = TextEditingController();
    
      final TextEditingController amountController = TextEditingController();
    
      late String search;
    
      late String cardNo;
    
      late String name;
    
      late String date;
    
      late String cvv;
    
      late String amount;
    
      final _selected = <String>[];
    
      late String documentId;
      late String eventImage;
      late String eventNamee;
      late String eventDate;
      late String eventLocation;
      late List<dynamic> eventGroups;
      bool _isNavigating = false;
    
      List<String> _searchResults = [];
    
      Future<List<String>> _executeSearch(String searchText) async {
        List<String> results = [];
    
        QuerySnapshot snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('events')
            .where('name', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: searchText)
            .where('name', isLessThanOrEqualTo: searchText + '\uf8ff')
            .get();
    
        snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
          results.add(doc['name']);
        });
    
        return results;
      }
    
      final eventsCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('events');
    
      Future<void> _navigateToEventDetails(String eventName) async {
        // Create a query to retrieve the document ID for the event with the specified eventName
        final query = eventsCollection.where('name', isEqualTo: eventName).limit(1);
    
        // Execute the query
        final querySnapshot = await query.get();
    
        // Get the document ID from the query snapshot
        documentId = querySnapshot.docs.first.id;
    
        // Get a reference to the document with the specified document ID
        final documentReference = eventsCollection.doc(documentId);
    
        // Get the details of the document using the documentReference
        final documentSnapshot = await documentReference.get();
    
        // Extract the event details from the snapshot
        eventImage = documentSnapshot.get('image');
        eventNamee = documentSnapshot.get('name');
        eventDate = documentSnapshot.get('date');
        eventLocation = documentSnapshot.get('location');
        eventGroups = documentSnapshot.get('groups');
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return AppBackgroundScreen(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: [
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 40, horizontal: 20),
                    child: Text(
                      "Donate To An Organization",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 24,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
    
                  CustomTextField(
                    label: "Search Event",
                    controller: searchController,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        _searchResults = [];
                      });
                      if (value.length > 2) {
                        _executeSearch(value).then((results) {
                          setState(() {
                            _searchResults = results;
                          });
                        });
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: _selected.length + _searchResults.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        if (index < _searchResults.length) {
                          final result = _searchResults[index];
                          return Column(
                            children: [
                              GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () async {
                                  if (!_isNavigating) {
                                    _isNavigating = true;
    
                                    // Call the async function
                                    await _navigateToEventDetails(result);
    
                                    // Navigate to the next screen
                                    // Navigator.push(
                                    //   context,
                                    //   MaterialPageRoute(
                                    //     builder: (context) => EventDetailsScreen(
                                    //       eventId: documentId,
                                    //       eventImage: eventImage,
                                    //       eventNamee: eventNamee,
                                    //       eventDate: eventDate,
                                    //       eventLocation: eventLocation,
                                    //       eventGroups: eventGroups,
                                    //     ),
                                    //   ),
                                    // );
                                    //_textController.clear();
    
                                    // Set the flag back to false to allow navigation to occur again
                                    _isNavigating = false;
                                  }
                                },
                                child: ListTile(
                                  leading: const Icon(Icons.star_border),
                                  title: Text(result),
                                ),
                              ),
                              const Divider(
                                color: Colors.grey,
                              ),
                            ],
                          );
                        } else {
                          // final selected = _selected[index - _searchResults.length];
                          // return ListTile(
                          //   title: Text(selected),
                          //   trailing: IconButton(
                          //     icon: const Icon(Icons.close),
                          //     onPressed: () {
                          //       setState(() {
                          //         _selected.removeAt(index - _searchResults.length);
                          //       });
                          //     },
                          //   ),
                          // );
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  // CustomTextField(
                  //     label: "Search Event",
                  //     onChanged: (value) {
                  //       search = value;
                  //       print(search);
                  //     },
                  //     controller: searchController),
                  CustomTextField(
                      label: "Card Number",
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        cardNo = value;
                        print(cardNo);
                      },
                      controller: cardController),
                  CustomTextField(
                      label: "Card Holder Name",
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        name = value;
                        print(name);
                      },
                      controller: nameController),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Flexible(
                        child: CustomTextField(
                            label: "Expiration Date",
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              date = value;
                              print(date);
                            },
                            controller: dateController),
                      ),
                      Flexible(
                        child: CustomTextField(
                            label: "CVV",
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              cvv = value;
                              print(cvv);
                            },
                            controller: cvvController),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  CustomTextField(
                      label: "Amount",
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        amount = value;
                        print(amount);
                      },
                      controller: amountController),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: CustomButton(
                      label: "Donate",
                      onPressed: () {
                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
                          content:
                              Container(child: Text("thank you for your Donation")),
                        ));
                        //Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/EventPaymentScreen');
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

this is the code for my customTextField I used in the donate screen:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
    
    class CustomTextField extends StatelessWidget {
      CustomTextField({
        required this.label,
        this.keyboardType = TextInputType.text,
        this.onTap,
        required this.onChanged,
        required this.controller,
      });
    
      String label;
      Function(String) onChanged;
      VoidCallback? onTap;
      final TextEditingController controller;
      TextInputType keyboardType;
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: TextField(
              keyboardType: keyboardType,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintStyle: const TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xff880c51),
                ),
                labelText: label,
                border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xff880c51))),
              ),
              controller: controller,
              onChanged: onChanged,
              onTap: onTap,
            ));
      }
    }
```

and in the end, this the code for my customBUtton:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    class CustomButton extends StatelessWidget {
      CustomButton({required this.label, required this.onPressed});
    
      String label;
      VoidCallback onPressed;
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: onPressed,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text(
              label,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
            ),
          ),
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              elevation: 0,
              shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                topRight: Radius.circular(20),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(20),
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
              ))),
        );
      }
    }
```

As you can see I have used the `shrinkWrap: true`  but the screen is still crashing. I can used SizedBox and giving it a fit height will build the screen but it will not be that much user-friendly. I want a perfect solution and not a work around.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are having `Expanded` widget inside `SingleChildScrolView`. You dont need to use scrollable widget on-after another. You can remove ListView and just use Column here, the top scrollable widget handle scroll event.

```dart
  return AppBackgroundScreen(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
            
            ...List.generate( itemCount: _selected.length + _searchResults.length, (index)
                 {  //your item Builder 

                    }
```